# Stored properties cannot be marked unavailable with '@available' XCode 15 , AAChartModel, AAChartKit

Tags: swift, xcode15, xcode-cloud

I'm encountering a persistent issue after transitioning my project from Xcode 14.3.1 to Xcode 15.0.1, with the iOS build target initially set at 13.0 and also tested on 14.0. The problem persists across both iOS targets. The specific error is: "Stored properties cannot be marked unavailable with '@available'" found in AAChartModel.swift at line 504. Despite attempting solutions suggested in similar GitHub issue threads, the error remains unresolved. This seems to be a compatibility issue with Xcode 15.0.1, particularly concerning the @available attribute usage on stored properties within the AAChartKit-Swift library.

[image]

I tried to resolve the package's latest version and researched package dependency, but I didn't fix it.

Comment: The package is going to have to be fixed. Apple announced this a couple of years ago, this setup was never supposed to work.

Comment: I uploaded package 9.0.0, but I got an error. same problems

Comment: Submit a bug report, create a branch and remove those from the comment it seems like there is already an alternative.

Comment: I submitted I fixed other package dependencies and it works. Thanks for supporting!